# d3.js Transition breaks in Angular - attrTween is calling the wrong 'this'

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js, this

I am trying to recreate this example of [d3.js v5 donut chart](https://bl.ocks.org/adamjanes/53eedf0b915fd8b20f04fd08bc24ff00) with transition as an Angular component, using the latest enter/update/exit pattern in d3 v5. Everything looked good until I played with the numbers in the sample data and the transition starts breaking. I have it isolated [here on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iuol7k).  You will see the behavior happening, but if you change the first value of the `oranges` object back to `200`, you will see it working just fine.  I kind of zoomed in on the cause and it seems to be in the arcTween function, where it needs to access the calling function 'this._current' but I think it is looking for it in the Angular component.

```
update(fruit) {
    this.svg
        .datum(this.data)
        .selectAll('path')
        .data(d3Shape.pie()
            .value((d: any) => d[fruit])
            .sort(null))
        .join(
            enter => enter
                .append('path')
                .text(d => d)
                .attr('fill', (d, i) => this.color(i))
                .attr('d', this.arc)
                .each(function (d) { this._current = d; }), // <--- This is the _current that I need access to 
            update => update
                .transition()
                .duration(2000)
                .attrTween('d', this.arcTween)
                .attr('fill', (d, i) => this.color(i))
                .attr('d', this.arc),
            exit => exit.remove()
    );
}


arcTween(a) {
  var i = d3Interpolate.interpolate(this._current, a); // It is assuming 'this' refers to a component level variable, should be the calling function scope
  this._current = i(0);
    return (t) => {
      return this.arc(i(t)); //  <-- this is referring correctly to the component arc variable
  };
}
```

Comment: `.attrTween('d', (a) => (this.arcTween(a)))`

Comment: @Hashbown I tried that, it still thinks `this._current` is a component level variable